# Spark Dataframe - using User Defined Function to add a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark

I'm still in a learning stage of `python`. In the following example (taken from [Method 3 of this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pyspark-dataframe-add-column-based-on-other-columns/)), the name of the User Defined Function (UDF) is `Total(...,...)`. But the author is calling it with a name `new_f(...,...)`.

**Question**: In the code below, how do we know that the function call `new_f(...,...)` should call the function `Total(...,...)`? What if there was another UDF function, say, `Sum(...,...)`. In that case, how the code would have known whether call `new_f(...,...)` means calling `Total(...,...)` or `Sum(...,...)`?

```
# import the functions as F from pyspark.sql
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
  
# define the sum_col
def Total(Course_Fees, Discount):
    res = Course_Fees - Discount
    return res
  
# integer datatype is defined
new_f = F.udf(Total, IntegerType())
  
# calling and creating the new
# col as udf_method_sum
new_df = df.withColumn(
  "Total_price", new_f("Course_Fees", "Discount"))
  
# Showing the Dataframe
new_df.show()
```

Comment: `new_f = F.udf(Total, IntegerType())` assigns the name `new_f` to that user defined function

Comment: @C.Nivs Got it. Thank you. Should be an `Answer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
new_f = F.udf(Total, IntegerType())
```

assigns the name new_f to that user defined function